# Picture not filling up the grid cell when converting from three column to two column

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive, masonry

I am designing an online photography portfolio and I am currently working with venobox + masonry layout. everything is working fine until I minimize the browser size, where a three-column layout turns in to a two-column layout. With the two-column layout, the image does not fill out the whole grid cell. The pink part is the background.[image]

Here is what I have so far:

```
            <div class="mywork" id="mywork">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/bikeL.jpg"><img src="image/bikeS.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/longL.jpg"><img src="image/longS.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/empL.jpg"><img src="image/empS.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/ctL.jpg"><img src="image/ctS.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/boatL.jpg"><img src="image/boatS.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/familyL.jpg"><img src="image/familyS.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/akL.jpg"><img src="image/akS.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/xyL.jpg"><img src="image/xyS.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/emp1L.jpg"><img src="image/emp1S.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/ysL.jpg"><img src="image/ysS.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/streetL.jpg"><img src="image/streetS.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/fzsL.jpg"><img src="image/fzsS.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/ys1L.jpg"><img src="image/ys1S.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/fuzhouL.jpg"><img src="image/fuzhouS.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/ctwtcL.jpg"><img src="image/ctwtcS.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/ocL.jpg"><img src="image/ocS.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/bambooL.jpg"><img src="image/bambooS.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/goldL.jpg"><img src="image/goldS.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/npL.jpg"><img src="image/npS.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/rfL.jpg"><img src="image/rfS.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/pilly1L.jpg"><img src="image/pilly1S.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/nycL.jpg"><img src="image/nycS.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div class="grid-item"><a class="lol" data-gall="myGallery" href="image/pillyL.jpg"><img src="image/pillyS.jpg" /></a></div>
       </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.grid-item {width: 33.33%;}
```

JS

```
 $('.grid').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: '.grid-item',
  });
```

Can anyone help in fixing this issue?

Comment: You would need to style the images in your css to cover its container how you want it to through .grid-item a img { YOUR STYLING HERE };

Comment: I've tried that, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use viewport width like this to solve your issue:

```
`.grid-item {width: 33.33vw;}`
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by adding img-fluid class to img.